# Benchmark.js module cannot find globally in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, global, npm

If I install [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) locally with `npm install benchmark` than everything works good:

```
require("benchmark") > Object
```

But when I try to install Benchmark globally with `-g` flag `npm install benchmark -g`, Nodejs cannot find the module (remove first the locally installed benchmark):

```
require("benchmark") > Error: Cannot find module 'benchmark'
```

I tryed under Windows and Linux both. The same results. **Locally work, globally not.** Can anyone help me WHY?

*The mongodb module works globally.*

Comment: Is this a global problem? Happens for all modules? Also, do you have something like NVM or N installed? (node version managers)

Comment: it only happens with benchmark. other packages work well. i have no nvm installed. did you tried this? does the error happens for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using `npm link`. For example - express - `npm link express`

```
npm install -g express
cd <your-application-development-path>
npm link express
```

A symbolic will be created linking express

```
xxx@xxx:~/Programming/web/foo$ ls -lrt node_modules
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxxx xxxx 4096 2011-12-21 17:07 .bin/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxxx xxxx   38 2011-12-21 17:07 express -> ../../../node/lib/node_modules/express/
```

Comment: First Zero! Thanks for your answer, but first: npm link dosen't work on windows, second, this is not the answer why benchmarkjs dosen't work globally, howewer other modules does. Did you tried to use benchmark globally not locally, and did it work? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Omnosis, Tested `npm link benchmark` and did `benchmark = require('benchmark');` and the script started fine. Though this was done on Ubuntu Linux. Not windows. A `ls -lrt` of node_modules shows
`benchmark -> ../../../node/lib/node_modules/benchmark/`

Do you have a script, I can run and test on Linux?

Not surprised `npm link` does not work on Windows as NTFS/FAT does not support symbolic links.

Comment: @FirstZero Actually your answer helps a lot. So I updated your answer to a more general answer. Thanks again!

Comment: anyone has a solution for this if host is windows (where symlinks indeed don't work)?

Comment: The only way is to just run `npm install <module name>` in Windows. `npm links` does not support symlinks are on NTFS. You can create shortcuts manually in node_modules folder or create sym links using `mlink` - cf - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another way to make it work when you install modules globally.
Try to set env variable `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Then your "require" should work fine.